# List Adapter não atualiza após remover

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

A situação é o seguinte:

Tenho um `SeparatedListAdapter` e com ele crio 3 seções pra minha `listview`. Dentro das seções, adiciono 3 `Adapters` e 3 `ArrayLists`.

O problema é que em cada um dos itens da lista, tem um botão de remover. Programei a remoção dentro de cada `Adapter` separado. Ele remove, o problema é que não atualiza a lista. Então, quando aperto o botão seguidamente, o *app* pára pois a lista fica vazia, porém não atualiza dinamicamente. Alguma ideia?

```
Button btt = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.remover_item);
    btt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Datastring.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Segue o código dos 3 Adapters simples.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;

    ArrayList<String> Datastring=new ArrayList<String>();

    public Adapter1(Context context,ArrayList<String> Items) {
        ctx = context;
        Datastring.addAll(Items);
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Datastring.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = (View) lInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
        }
        TextView text=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_content1);
        text.setText(Datastring.get(position));
        Button btt = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.remover_item);
        btt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Datastring.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

E o código do SeparatedListAdapter:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.content.Context; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public final Map<String,Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String,Adapter>();
public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;
public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;

public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context) {
    headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.header); 
}

public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {
    this.headers.add(section);
    this.sections.put(section, adapter);
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
    Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
    int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

    // check if position inside this section
    if(position == 0) return section;
    if(position < size) return adapter.getItem(position - 1);

    // otherwise jump into next section
    position -= size;
    }
    return null;
}

public int getCount() {
    int total = 0;
for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
    total += adapter.getCount() + 1;
return total;
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    int total = 1;
    for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
        total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
    return total;
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int type = 1;
    for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

    // check if position inside this section
    if(position == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
    if(position < size) return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);

    // otherwise jump into next section
    position -= size;
    type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
    }
    return -1;
}

public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int sectionnum = 0;
    for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
    Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
    int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

    // check if position inside this section
    if(position == 0) {
        return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent); // this is where     your header names will get bind. correctly.
    }
    if(position < size) {
        return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);
    }

    // otherwise jump into next section
    position -= size;
    sectionnum++;
}
return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}
```

Comment: Acho que vamos precisar de mais código, precisamente do código dos `Adapter`s.

Comment: Poderia testar com o `notifyDataSetInvalidated`? A diferença para o `notifyDataSetChanged` é que nele o número de elementos não mudou, apenas os dados de cada item.

Comment: notifyDataSetInvalidated funcionou. Porém, apenas quando dou um scroll na lista, quanbdo "mexo" com ela. Estaticamente ele não remove.

Comment: Consegui resolver. Adicionei              adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new CascadeDataSetObserver()); ao método addSection() no Grande Adapter.

Comment: Agora uma outra dúvida. E para adicionar elementos dinamicamente ? Estou tentando pelo mesmo conceito mas ainda não obtive solução. Alguma ideia ?

Comment: @LucasSoares se tem outra dúvida crie uma nova pergunta, pode até linkar esta para ajudar a compreender o problema. Já agora se tem a resposta à sua pergunta aconselho-o a criar uma resposta e depois aceitá-la.

Comment: @LucasSoares só reparei agora que a dúvida já tem mais de uma ano, mas sinta-se à vontade de criar a resposta mesmo assim.